# Pending Transaction

Tags: transaction, pending

I know this question has been here before but I did what was already mentioned and still nothing happened.

Problem: I sent 250 Miotas 24hrs ago from an exchange (Coinone) to my Wallet (V. 2.5.7 - IRI 1.4.2.1).

The transaction appears as pending. The address was a newly created one just for that transaction. Two transactions appear as pending. 1 with 0 Miota and another one with the 250 Mi for the same address. Both of them Pending.

Some facts:

- I already transferred money to this wallet. So, the wallet is working fine.
- When I check the Hash in iotasear.ch the transaction appears as Unconfirmed.
- I already change the Node 4 times to see if there was a problem of traffic. I chose the least congested node in iota.dance.
- I already re-attached many times in each of the different nodes.
- I also promoted the transaction several times.
- I reattached the two transactions many times. The one with 0 Mi and the one with 250 Mi.

[image: screenshot of the transaction states]

I really don't know what else to do. I need a little of professional help here. I still have a lot more iotas that I need to transfer from Coinone. I transferred everything from Bitfinex and it was confirmed in 5 minutes after the transfer.

I know that IOTA is still in beta and I understand the things that need to be ironed out. That's why I am here asking for some help after trying everything described before.

Comment: any answers correct?

Answer (score 1):

**Why are there 2 transactions?**

The empty transaction is the wallet telling the network your address exists. This is not required to send transactions to the network.

The transaction with 250 MIOTA is, as expected, your exchange withdrawal.

**Why is it not confirmed?**

The answer lies in the way a tip (unconfirmed transaction) is selected for confirmation. Starting with the genesis block you do a random walk until you find an unconfirmed transaction. If this transaction is old, then it is ignored. There is a probability that your transaction is never found. That is why you need to reattach and promote your transaction. Reattach and promote redo the work and give yourself another shot at being picked at random. You can view the current confirmation status at https://tanglemonitor.com as Avg. Conf. Rate (at the time of writing this its at 35%, timestamp:20180522).

**How do I confirm it?**

The new trinity wallet will automatically promote and reattach transactions. If you want to promote it manually you can, or you can give it to http://iotareatta.ch where you can have remotely do the work. This site will keep reattaching every 10min until it is confirmed. It is never guaranteed that your transaction will be confirmed, but a [98.9% certainty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation) is enough certainty that many people would bet their life on it.

Answer (score 0):

The 0i Transaction can be ignored. You don't need it to confirm. For the transaction with value, you can use promoting and reattaching Websites like:

[pro.iota.fm](http://pro.iota.fm/)

[Rajiv Power tool](https://rajivshah3.github.io/iota-pow-er/reattach.html)

[reattach.online](http://www.reattach.online/)

You can check the overall performance of the network [here](http://analytics.iotaledger.net/stresstest.table).