# What can be done when a transaction has been pending for a long time and reattaching and promoting has not helped?

Tags: transaction, pending, reattach

The answer to [this other question](https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/1570/pending-transaction) has some information about reattaching and promoting a transaction that has been pending for a long time.

Sometimes however that does not result in the confirmation of a transaction.

So I have a couple of questions about what could be done in that sort of situations:

1. The top-rated answer to [this question](https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/33/how-does-reattaching-a-transaction-increase-the-chance-for-confirmation) mentions pushing "a new
   zero-valued transaction that approves your transaction". What would
   be the steps for doing this?
2. Other than that, does the IOTA ecosystem provide mechanisms for
   debugging a transaction?

Comment: "pushing a new zero-valued transsaction that approves your transaction" is what know is known as promoting.